# No Shuffle in iTunes 12.2?

Tags: itunes, mac

Is there any shuffle option in iTunes 12.2 for Mac?
(I haven't found one) and why Apple has deliberately removed the main feature of any music player?
I mean no one listens to music in playlist/A-Z order.

PS: Why downvote. They did remove the shuffle button from most of the interface and made it a bit harder to access.

It used to be here:

[image]

There is doesn't seem to be an option to shuffle all.

I selected all songs and there is no option on right click:

[image]

The option in the panel menu seems to be there, but it doesn't affect the order in which iTunes plays my queue.

[image]

Yeah they did leave Shuffle on playlists, but who uses playlists in iTunes anyways, right? I mean I usually just shuffle over all my library and my guess is majority does the same. Now I need to create a playlist only to shuffle over all the trucks and update it on every update of the library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A note after the question update…
Shuffle isn't as random as you think. It's a one-off process that is only re-computed every time you switch shuffle off & on again. Until you do that, the previously generated shuffle can be stepped back & forth in exactly the same pseudo-random order.

Also - if you have manually enqueued songs, it will only shuffle songs *after* the manually added tracks…

[image]

Shuffle & Repeat are always available in the Controls menu… & always searchable...

[image]

If iTunes is actually playing [or has been playing & now paused], it's in the top centre panel, as always…
The only time it doesn't appear here is before you start to play the first song since launch, or after a manual Clear of the Up Next list.

[image]

In all views except My Music > Song & Album, it's in the top of the main window…

[image]

Anywhere else it's usually on the right-click menu…

Comment: But I have a queue and it doesn't get shuffled when I turn the Shuffle on.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: @VsevolodGlumov the queue was just added to allow iTunes to put up an annoying modal dialog when you want to change the music you're listening to.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger thanks, now I know I'm not the only one sceptical about certain Apple's decisions on this site.